Metaplex candy machine v3
what will the python/js script look like to display all the stages and guards?
I've tried a lot of options, but I keep making mistakes.

Example taken from the docs https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/guards
import {
  fetchCandyMachine,
  fetchCandyGuard,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine'

const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, candyMachineAddress)
const candyGuard = await fetchCandyGuard(umi, candyMachine.mintAuthority)

candyGuard.guards // All guard settings.
...


